# expo-doctor: How to skip expo-doctor check for certain scripts in package.json

Tags: expo

When i try to run `npx expo-doctor@latest` i get the following error

```
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✖ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check for issues with metro config
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Detailed check results:

The following scripts in package.json conflict with the contents of node_modules/.bin: eslint, tsc.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.
```

Upon debugging i found the issue is with having the following scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "eslint": "eslint --ext .ts",
  },
```

I know changing the script name would resolve the issue but i have some generic workflows that use this command. Is there a way to skip this check?

I didn;t find a way to skip this. Any one please help